# Update global variable after click event (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, onclick, maps, global-variables

It sounds super simple, but I am looking to update my global variables ('latitude' and 'longitude') every time the map is clicked, as need to use these values elsewhere. Updating the variables from inside the function does not apply. Thus, the alerts show 'undefined'.

Any guidance would be much appreciated :-)

```js
// set global vars
var latitude;
var longitude;
var popup = L.popup();

// create function to populate pop-up and global vars
function onMapClick(e) {  // show pop-up when map is clicked
  popup .setLatLng(e.latlng) .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString()) .openOn(mymap); // populate pop-up with lat/long values
  latitude = e.latlng.lat // populate global var to use elsewhere
  longitude = e.latlng.lng // populate global var to use elsewhere
}

mymap.on('click', onMapClick);  // call function when cliked on map

alert(latitude) // output is 'undefined'
alert(longitude) // output is 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 1):

The variables get updated. The only thing is that your `alert` calls have **already happened**. They aren't going to get done again when the click happens unless you write code to do them again when the click happens. Just move the `alert` calls (or whatever you're really doing with that information) **into** the click handler:

```js
// set global vars
var latitude;
var longitude;
var popup = L.popup();

// create function to populate pop-up and global vars
function onMapClick(e) {  // show pop-up when map is clicked
    popup .setLatLng(e.latlng).setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString()).openOn(mymap); // populate pop-up with lat/long values
    latitude = e.latlng.lat; // populate global var to use elsewhere
    longitude = e.latlng.lng; // populate global var to use elsewhere
    alert(latitude);  // <===== Moved
    alert(longitude); // <===== Moved
}

mymap.on('click', onMapClick);  // call function when cliked on map
```

This also means you may well not need the globals at all:

```js
// set global vars
var popup = L.popup();

// create function to populate pop-up and global vars
function onMapClick(e) {  // show pop-up when map is clicked
    popup .setLatLng(e.latlng).setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString()).openOn(mymap); // populate pop-up with lat/long values
    alert(e.latlng.lat);
    alert(e.latlng.lng);
}

mymap.on('click', onMapClick);  // call function when cliked on map
```